# slide animation works well in firefox but stutters in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, animation

I am building a website in which a center div if pushed out of the screen when you click a button by another div that is positioned either to the left, top or right of the page.

The left, top and right divs will be loaded using jquery ajax and is animated using css3.

Here is the page I am talking about:

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/index.html

Try clicking the left eye in Chrome and Firefox. You will see that the animation is smooth in Firefox but stutters in chrome.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I was also wondering if anyone knew how I could potentially speed up the website/make the transitions look smoother.

thanks for any help you guys might have

best,

katie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can clearly see the jerkiness in Chrome.

CSS3 animations do not necessarily run smoothly if you are doing lots of other things in the browser.  How smoothly they run depends upon what else you're trying to do at the same time and how the internal implementation in the browser handles that.

From my experience with a CSS3 slideshow that uses fancy CSS3 transitions, the best way to allow them to run smoothly is to NOT do substantial things with your code at the same time that you want the animation to be running smoothly.  Here are some ways to maximize your chances of a smooth run:

1. Preload resources you may need during the time of the animation.
2. Don't kick of any javascript functions during the run time of the animation.
3. Avoid loading images during the animation.
4. For things that you want to run after the animation, trigger their operation via the completion function of the animation (so they don't start until the animation is done).
5. If you want something built and ready when the animation is done, then build it first before starting the animation and have it hidden and ready to go before you start the animation.
6. Don't modify the DOM during your animation (other than what is required specifically for the animation).

More specifically in your page, I see jerkiness in the slide transition, but at the same time as it is sliding, I see the browser trying to load the new content that displays during the slide.  It is likely that the loading and displaying of that new content is contributing to the jerkiness of the slide transition.  I'd suggest that you either wait until the slide is done to start loading the new content or you preload the new content before starting the slide.  I've found that some browsers get jerky in CSS3 transitions even when the browser is just loading images over the network.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any JS going on, is there?

Comment: i believe the $.ajax function i am calling is jquery

Comment: @katiebekell are you updating the div you're going to show as you animate?

Comment: @JuanMendes - I see new stuff being loaded at the same time the content is trying to slide.

Comment: how would I best implement what I am trying to do. I believe what I am trying to achieve is relatively self explanatory but let me know if I can elaborate at all

Comment: I see it now, definitely don't want to change the content of the div that is being animated, specially when it's the entire screen @katiebekell Preload the content before animating

Comment: @katiebekell - I added more specfic observations and suggestions about your page to my answer.

Comment: how can I force my slideOut() code finish before ajax is executed. As of now, I believe my thebest route to take is to slide the div, then set a beforeSend loading GIF in the page that slides in, and finally when the page is finished loading, replace the GIF with the data from ajax.

Comment: @katiebekell - You need to add an event listener for the transition end event that signals the end of the CSS3 transtion and trigger your ajax code based on that event.  Your code also looks like you are calling `SlideOut()` twice in a row if the id matches anything in your `if/else` loop which is not ideal.

Comment: would it make the most sense to put it before the if/else statements or nested inside of them?

Comment: @katiebekell - There are many ways to structure your code.  I would recommend adding the event listener in your `SlideOut()` function and pass a callback function to `SlideOut()` as an argument that you call from the event listener.  You will have to remove the event listener when the animation is done to avoid getting it installed more than once.

Comment: I have never used event listeners and am having a hard time finding some relevant code online. do you think you could show me a simple example of what you mean? thanks for all the help im going to +1 u

Comment: @katiebekell - you can search Google for "transitionend" and find lots of examples.  I always start with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and [here's another](http://marakana.com/static/bookshelf/css3_transitions_tutorial/javascript.html).  You can find lots more on Google.  One complication is that different browsers use a different name for the event so you have to incorporate code to know which event name to use.

Comment: So how are you supposed to make a loading spinner? In my situation, I want to show the spinner precisely when I'm doing the heavy work so the user has something to look at while waiting. It feels like this should be possible, but using css transforms results in stuttering.

Comment: @MaxStrater - I'd probably suggest a small animated GIF, but you'd still have to see how well that works in various browsers under load.